# SSIS Script Task C# Out of Memory

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, out-of-memory

A few years ago I implemented a SSIS package and C# Script task to cycle through the creation of files.  In short, it reads data out of SQL Server, stores to datatable, applies basic formatting, and writes to a text file.  The source data has grown to a large size and I am now getting an out of memory exception while processing files with 4-8 million records.  After some research I believe the problem may be in the datatable holding all those rows in memory but am at a loss how to architect around this.  I am barely a C# novice.  I could recreate this package to use the standard data flow but it would increase the complexity of the package greatly as there are multiple file formats based on the source tables in the query. I would also be subject to future metadata changes.
I would like to keep this C# read and write process but solve the memory issue, any ideas?

```
#region Namespaces
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
#endregion

namespace ST_35510fa90f9946dd823e277e917a3dc0
{

    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {
   
        public void Main()
        {
            try
            {

                //Declare Variables
                string DestinationFolder = Dts.Variables["User::TARGET_FILE_PATH"].Value.ToString();
                string QueryStage = Dts.Variables["User::QUERY_STAGE"].Value.ToString();
                string FileName = Dts.Variables["User::TARGET_FILE_NAME"].Value.ToString();
                string FileDelimiter = Dts.Variables["User::TARGET_FILE_DELIM"].Value.ToString();
          
                //USE ADO.NET Connection from SSIS Package to get data from table
                SqlConnection myADONETConnection = new SqlConnection();
                myADONETConnection = (SqlConnection)(Dts.Connections["ADO_MED_AFF_BIO_PROVIDER"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction) as SqlConnection);


                //Read data from table or view to data table
                string query = QueryStage;
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, myADONETConnection);
                //myADONETConnection.Open();
                DataTable d_table = new DataTable();
                d_table.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
                myADONETConnection.Close();

                string FileFullPath = DestinationFolder + "\\" + FileName + ".txt";

                StreamWriter sw = null;
                sw = new StreamWriter(FileFullPath, false);

                // Write the Header Row to File
                int ColumnCount = d_table.Columns.Count;
                for (int ic = 2; ic < ColumnCount; ic++)
                {
                    sw.Write("\"" + d_table.Columns[ic] + "\"")


                        ;
                    if (ic < ColumnCount - 1)
                    {
                        sw.Write(FileDelimiter);
                    }
                }
                sw.Write(sw.NewLine);

                // Write All Rows to the File
                foreach (DataRow dr in d_table.Rows)
                {
                    for (int ir = 2; ir < ColumnCount; ir++)
                    {
                        if (!Convert.IsDBNull(dr[ir]))

                        {
                            if (dr[ir] is DateTime dt)
                            {
                                // use DateTime's specific string rendering
                                sw.Write(

                                    "\"" + dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "\""

                                    );
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                // fall back to standard string rendering
                                sw.Write(
                                    "\"" + dr[ir].ToString() + "\""
                                    );
                            }
                        }

                        if (ir < ColumnCount - 1)
                        {
                            sw.Write(FileDelimiter);
                        }
                    }
                    sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
                }
                sw.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }

        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: A quick search and I found multiple articles related to using a data table with large numbers of rows.  All of them show that you should clear and dispose of the data table once you are done.  If that doesn't help - then you can force garbage collection - and if that doesn't work, then you are probably running with a debugger which holds onto the memory.

Comment: Are you running the package in Visual Studio or on a server? If on a server, are you in 32 or 64 bit mode? Don't know, check it https://billfellows.blogspot.com/2015/02/is-my-ssis-package-running-in-32-or-64.html

Comment: If you don't have enough memory to load the entire `DataTable` in memory then... don't. Use the [`SqlDataReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader) that's returned by `SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()` to iterate over the rows one at a time, in a streaming fashion. While you're doing that you can fix the quoting issues you have - any column names or data values containing `"` characters will be breaking the serialized output, ref: [RFC 4180 Common Format and MIME Type for Comma-Separated Values (CSV) Files](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180)